# Does the number of shards and replicas have any effect on disk size?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, diskspace

My ES nodes are using the default settings. 5 primary shards, replicas = 1.
Does changing the settings from 5 to 3 shards and 1 replica have any effect on disk space used or is disk size solely affected by indices and documents?

My nodes keep running out of space and I'm wondering if changing number of shards and replicas 
will affect disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reducing shards won't help, you will still have the same amount of data, it's just won't be sharded as much. You can decrease the disk space by reducing number of replicas, disable **_all** and **_source** field and use special mapping (E.g. you could use keyword analyzer for all strings, throw away field norms, term vectors, etc. plus disabling _all and _source. This saves some space but the price to pay is less "searchability" - careful testing is required if your search requirements are still met.)